# Table cell borders with multiple thicknesses (or a div boundary)?

Tags: html, css

I know how to have a border set with a style of **double** on a table cell or div boundary.

But how about this (extract from Microsoft Word):

[image: Extract from Microsoft Word]

It has a thick and thin border. Can we do this easily with HTML / CSS?

Thank you.

Update:

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<div style="border-bottom:1px black double">
    SAMPLE TEXT</div>

</body>

</html>
```

It will generate a double line, but with both lines having the **same** thickness.

In the Microsoft Word example it has two lines, but one is thicker. See? Can we do this with CSS/HTML?

Comment: could you specify what exactly you want to achieve, and consider sharing your code

Comment: I have just updated the question with some code and a further explanation.

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/sd35acug/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create something like the double lines in your image, you can create an additional container around your text:

```
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner">
    Text
  </span>
</div>
```

You can then style those lines like this:

```
.outer {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.inner {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!